# Is the Concentration skill needed to cast spells, or is it just a nice thing to have?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, skills, concentration

I was never entirely clear on how it works for spells.

Answer (score 8):

Concentration is used to resist being interrupted, cast without provoking attacks, or get a spell out in a difficult situation.

According to the [SRD](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/skills/concentration.htm), when you take damage while casting a spell (typically from an attack of opportunity or from a readied attack), you have to make a concentration check DC of 10+ the damage that you took while casting.

Defensive Casting lets you roll before you cast, to not provoke attacks of opportunity for casting the spell, with a DC of 15 + The level of the spell you're trying to cast.

On the page I linked, there is also a table of examples of situations that would require a concentration check to cast a spell, such as bouncing around on a horse, being Grappled, or in the middle of a storm.

The Concentration skill is not *required* to cast spells, but it *is* very, very useful.

Comment: It might be useful to mention that failing the Concentration check when casting on the defensive does *not* mean that the caster provokes an attack of opportunity but, instead, that the caster loses the spell! A caster *really* wants to succeed on those checks.